# Jboss Jndi name not bound

Tags: jboss, jms, jndi

I'm get frustrated with a problem and I spend hours trying to resolve it !! 
The problem is. I tried to lookup a topic (MyBestTopic) already declared in my jboss server, but I have this exception

```
2014-09-12 11:50:13,232 ERROR [STDERR] javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: MyBestTopic not bound
2014-09-12 11:50:13,239 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:529)
2014-09-12 11:50:13,239 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:537)
2014-09-12 11:50:13,239 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getObject(NamingServer.java:543)
```

In my java code, I tried to retrieve the topic like this :

```
dest = (Topic) jndiContext.lookup("topic/MesBestTopic");
```

Looking at the startup of jboss server, I can see that the topic is well bound with the correct name:

```
2014-09-12 11:49:43,261 INFO  [org.jboss.mq.server.jmx.Topic.MyBestTopic] Bound to JNDI name: topic/MyBestTopic
```

Finally when I see the tree of jndiView on the jmx-console, the topic also well deployed :

```
Global JNDI Namespace


+- XAConnectionFactory (class: org.jboss.mq.SpyXAConnectionFactory)
+- TransactionSynchronizationRegistry (class:     com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionSynchronizationRegistryImple)
+- TopicConnectionFactory (class: org.jboss.naming.LinkRefPair)
+- UIL2ConnectionFactory[link -> ConnectionFactory] (class: javax.naming.LinkRef)
+- UserTransactionSessionFactory (proxy: $Proxy15 implements interface   org.jboss.tm.usertx.interfaces.UserTransactionSessionFactory)
+- console (class: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext)
|   +- PluginManager (proxy: $Proxy48 implements interface org.jboss.console.manager.PluginManagerMBean)
+- UIL2XAConnectionFactory[link -> XAConnectionFactory] (class: javax.naming.LinkRef)
+- HTTPConnectionFactory (class: org.jboss.mq.SpyConnectionFactory)
+- QueueConnectionFactory (class: org.jboss.naming.LinkRefPair)
+- topic (class: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext)
|   +- **MyBestTopic** (class: org.jboss.mq.SpyTopic)
+- HTTPXAConnectionFactory (class: org.jboss.mq.SpyXAConnectionFactory)
```

The same java works fine in an other jboss with the same deployed topic and datasource !!!

I'm very confused of what doing... Anyone has ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find out my problem.

That's was to fact that I have two jboss running on the same machine. One Jboss already the port 1099 for jms. The other uses another port (10099). In my code, I have specified the port 1099, it would never work because this one is used by the other jboss!!!

Hope this could help others...